# Highest value of machine translation metrics

Tags: natural-language, model-evaluation, machine-translation

Does anyone knows the highest and lowest values of the common machine translation metrics $BLEU_{1-4}$, $METEOR$, $ROUGE_{L}$, and $CIDEr$ and $CIDEr-D$?

I know that for BLEU is 1, correct? Does the same stands for all other metrics mentioned above?

Also, what about $CIDEr$ and $CIDEr-D$ metric? What is the maximum value?

Answer (score 1):

- $BLEU_{1-n}$: minimum 0, maximum 1.
- $METEOR$: minimum 0, maximum 1.
- $ROUGE_{n}$, $ROUGE_{L}$, $ROUGE_{S}$: minimum 0, maximum 1.
- $CIDEr$: minimum 0, maximum 1. Original reference: {1}.
- $CIDEr-D$?: minimum 0, maximum 1.  $CIDEr-D$ = CIDEr Defended, named as such as it is more robust to gaming effects. Original reference: {1}.

Keep in mind that sometime people uses percentage. E.g., one could say $ROUGE_{n}=40\%$.

{2} goes over all these metrics in the context of the image captioning evaluation. Note that for ROUGE there are some small differences between how {2} (and many other papers) present ROUGE and the original ROUGE implementation (e.g., it does have stemming).

---

References:

- {1} Vedantam, Ramakrishna, C. Lawrence Zitnick, and Devi Parikh. "CIDEr: Consensus-based image description evaluation." In Proceedings of the IEEE conference on computer vision and pattern recognition, pp. 4566-4575. 2015. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=2428149707553201565&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5 ; https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5726
- {2} Chen, Xinlei, Hao Fang, Tsung-Yi Lin, Ramakrishna Vedantam, Saurabh Gupta, Piotr Dollár, and C. Lawrence Zitnick. "Microsoft COCO captions: Data collection and evaluation server." arXiv preprint arXiv:1504.00325 (2015).;  https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=4232572309886474756&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5 ; https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.00325